# How to run macro in word without opening it?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to run macro in word without opening it.
I went through same question asked before.
Solution is:

```
Dim Word    
Dim WordDoc

Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")    
Word.Visible = False

Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.open("D:\working_folder\abc.doc")    
Word.Run "<macroname>"    
WordDoc.Save

Word.Quit        
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set Word = Nothing
```

This is working well for me too but in this case file name is specific (`"abc.doc"`).

What if I want to run macro for all word files which are in the same folder?
The Macro is defined in all those files, I just want to know how to get all filenames in a folder.

Comment: Is this question about how you would enumerate all files in a folder or how to run a Macro that is defined in a file on other files?

Comment: I have macro to run in all MS word files whichever posted in particular folder without opening a file as I get files in bulk to specific folder through FTP

Comment: Yes, that much is clear. Is the marco defined in all those files (you just want to know how to get all filesnames in a folder) or are you trying to run a marco on a file other than the defining file (different question)

Comment: Yes..macro is defined in all those files.  Just want to know how to get all filenames in a folder (budding coder)

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but something like this:

```
Dim Word, fldr, f    
Dim WordDoc

Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")    
Word.Visible = False

fldr = "D:\working_folder\"
f = Dir(fldr & "*.doc*")

Do while f<>""

    Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.open(fldr & f)    
    Word.Run "<macroname>"    
    WordDoc.Save
    WordDoc.Close
    f = Dir()

Loop

Word.Quit        
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set Word = Nothing
```

You can't run a macro without opening the file which contains it though.

Comment: Specific Error Message? 

Having used similar procedures, I see no reason why Tim's solution shouldn't work - unless, maybe, you try to run a macro that automates mail-merge.

Comment: Error: Type mismatch: 'Dir'
Code: 800A000D